# Unable to print specific values from an ANOVA table

Tags: r, null, statistics, anova, p-value

I am using the code below:

```
data2 <- aov(y~x1+groupcategory+x1:groupcategory,data=df6)
data4 <- summary(data2)
data5 <- data4["Pr(>F)"]
```

data5 is printing 'NULL' but I am unsure as to why!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of summary(aov(..)) is a list. Do

```
data4 = summary(aov(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars))
data4[[1]]["Pr(>F)"]
             Pr(>F)    
cyl         < 2e-16 ***
disp        0.03091 *  
hp          0.26103    
drat        0.14064    
wt          0.00324 ** 
qsec        0.46166    
vs          0.89317    
am          0.16586    
gear        0.71365    
carb        0.81218    
Residuals              
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks!  Also, when I print this:    for (k in 1:29){                                                  
                   df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x1 = c(rep(distances, 2)),
                    y = c(rbinom(e,n_trials,pr), rbinom(e,n_trials,pr1)),
                    groupcategory = groupcategory, id = c(rep(k,12)))) }      It gives me each ID only 6 times, 

                                      but should it not print the ID 12 times not 6 times

Comment: Hi @Caledonian26, try not to ask something separate under comments. Just this once, i would say you do data.frame(..., id = k)